# WCF Binding advice for dispatched units

Tags: wcf, architecture

I plan to build a WCF based application that will allow for users in the field to be connected to a dispatch center and be able to get updates on their calls and request information from the system while they are performing their calls.

I am looking for advice on how to connect the clients to the server.

I was thinking that I would use NetTcpBinding.

But do I use a callback structure or do I just make a netTcpBiding connection in both directions to maintain the connection?

I will probably only have about 100 online at any time, and there will be a dispatching center that would update or send the field personnel out to the client sites.

We would use cellphone data to transfer the data over the internet and a product called Netmotion that will let the client computer look like it is setting on the home network.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the clients will not be online all the time, or there could be connection interruptions (you're using mobile data, after all), TCP/IP is not very reliable.

You could have a connection faulted mid-stream and all sorts of other connectivity issues. On top of that you will have to do a lot of error handling for every exceptional situation you encounter (and you won't encounter them all during development).

I'll assume clients are not embedded devices of some kind, but laptops (or tablets starting this fall:) ).

Therefore I recommend using WCF over MSMQ (transactional) for several reasons:

- Reliable communication and message delivery with 0 data loss. This applies if you make your queues transactional and take advantage of distributed transactions.
- Undelivered messages get back to you (in dead letter queues) and you can do logging, troubleshooting or send them back for further processing.
- Disconnected communication. Clients don't even have to be online when sending messages. They're just queued in a local MSMQ and forwarded to their destination when the client comes online. Same applies for the server.

This would be suitable in your situation because as far as I can see you don't really need two-way communication. Dispatching center sends a work order, is received (when online) by the client, the client does something with it and later sends a status back to the server.

In any case, you should model your messages in such a way they contain only mandatory metadata, easy to send over the air.

An easy sample of WCF client sending over MSMQ is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751490.aspx).

Comment: I have been looking at MSMQ and it seems easier to use than the netTcpBinding.  I need to see how it will work across the inet..Thank you for the direction. I will have to see how it works with multiple clients and figure out how to track what message if from which client, but that shouldnt be too hard.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this design pattern for the publish/subscribe model.

[MSDN publish subscribe pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254.aspx)